# Javascript: function not defined error message

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple example code, 3 textboxes. If I write numbers in the first two, it multiplies them and writes the result in the third one. However, if I run the code, I get an error saying: "ReferenceError: calc is not defined". Am I missing something?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script language="text/javascript">
    function calc()
    {
        var txt1 = (float) document.getElementById('text1').value;
        var txt2 = (float) document.getElementById('text2').value;
        document.getElementById('text3').value = (txt1 * txt2);
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="text1" name="text1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" onkeypress="calc();"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="text3" name="text3"></td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: Whoever wrote that "(float)" is causing the problem, was right. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `parseFloat` to cast to float

```
function calc()
{
    var txt1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text1').value);
    var txt2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text2').value);
    document.getElementById('text3').value = (txt1 * txt2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Try changing

```
<script language="text/javascript">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

If you would like to use the **deprecated** `language` attribute you could do:

```
<script language="Javascript">
```

Additionally, as others have already pointed out that to get a float from a string you can use `parseFloat` and pass the string as a parameter. Using `(float)` is often used in **Java** to convert from a numeric type such as `double` or `int` to `float`.

2) Try changing

```
var txt1 = (float) document.getElementById('text1').value;
var txt2 = (float) document.getElementById('text2').value;
```

to

```
var txt1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text1').value;
var txt2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text2').value;
```

Comment: Useful information but won't actually fix the problem.

Comment: @Peter Herdenborg Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting that error is because the function you have defined there is invalid, so it is not loaded. The problem lies with (float) - you can't typecast like that in JavaScript.

Use the parseFloat() function as follows:

```
var txt1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text1').value);
```

Note that Rajesh is also correct in that you need to change

```
<script language="text/javascript">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

The complete, correct script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calc()
    {
        var txt1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text1').value);
        var txt2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text2').value);
        document.getElementById('text3').value = (txt1 * txt2);
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat()` instead of `(float)`

Answer (score -1):

try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tb7yv0pn/)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    function calc()
    {
        var txt1 = document.getElementById('text1');
        var txt2 = document.getElementById('text2');
        document.getElementById('text3').value = (parseFloat(txt1.value) * parseFloat(txt2.value));
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="text2" name="text2"   value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="text3" name="text3" onkeypress="calc()" value=""></td>
       </tr>
   </table>     
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

use this line `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">`

Comment: This won't help and the language attribute is deprecated.

Answer (score -2):

I is the (float) casting that causes the problem.

Comment: Okay, what and how does it cause? Also how to solve it?

Comment: You see the update comment from the question? So thx a lot for stupidly downvote ...